# Best opinion over looping multiple sites over a looping script

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have an xml sitemap. I want to run a script over all links on the map. Here is the code that provides me the links.

```
            from lxml import etree
            import urllib
            from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

            my_firsturl = 'https://www.desertessence.com/sitemap.xml'

            pagedata = urllib.request.urlopen(my_firsturl)
            mapa = soup(pagedata, "lxml-xml")


            print (mapa)
```

On other HTML sites, I can call `[0], [1]` to call a single row. This is so I can create a loop. I ultimately want to feed it multiple maps and have the script repeat. Currently I am unable to call speciic links and lack the knowledge even after going over documentation.

Comment: .. and your specific problem doing this is ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to urllib3 
http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

and use the builtin poolmanager. 
http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.1/managers.html

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.desertessence.com/sitemap.xml'

req = urllib3.PoolManager(10)
res = req.request('GET', url)
mapa = BeautifulSoup(res.data, "lxml")
for links in mapa.select("url loc"):
    print(links.text)
```

Comment: `TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'`

Comment: Ha! Thanks SIM!

Answer (score 0):

So just call a function with the map or list of map. Dont see a real issue

```
def evaluate_maps(maps):
  if isinstance(maps, list):
    for map in maps:
      evaluate_map(map)
  else:
    # if its one map
    evaluate_map(maps)

def evaluate_map(map):
  # do stuff for 1 map
  # try using yield for better/faster result
```

Comment: did I get something wrong I get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`